# How to avoid methods calling each other in a chain?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a C# class where I use a set of methods to filter out a List. I essentially do this by one method from inside the other and so on. So a( values) does some filtering, based on the output calls b(List values) or exits, b(List values) does some filtering and based on the output calls c(List values).

I want to remove this method chaining code from and control everything from the method which calls a(List values). I can use if-else-if but that will lead to too many if-else-ifs which I dont think is so great.

Are there any design patterns to solve this? Or some algo? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Gaurav

Comment: Why?  You haven't given enough info, but moving everything to one method doesn't sound like an improvement.

Comment: why do you not combine filters into one filter?

Comment: The question is not clear. What property of output does `a` decide whether it should call `b` or exit? What is output, the filtered list? Please give some example using code. Maybe using hypothetical filtering and deciding algorithm.

Comment: A code snippet might help people help you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are discribinq sounds like typical scenario to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) with Iterator pattern (it can be implemented in C# easily with [iterator blocks](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/06/07/liberty.html)).

```
var results =
     someCollection
        .Where(c => c.SomeProperty < someValue * 2)
        .Where(c => c.OtherProperty == "hi")
        .OrderBy(c => c.AnotherProperty)
        .Select(c => new {c.SomeProperty, c.OtherProperty});
```

Or as query expression:

```
var results =  from c in SomeCollection
           where c.SomeProperty < someValue * 2
           where c.OtherProperty == "Hi"
           orderby c.AnotherProperty
           select new {c.SomeProperty, c.OtherProperty};
```

You can chain as many operations as you wish. Of course much more advanced operations, shuch as joins and grouping, are also available.

I recommend Jon Skeet's [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) book if you really want to learn these techniques (and many others).

Comment: Why I think it does not work is that he wants to invoke a filter **depending on the output of previous**. In your example it would mean `.Where(c => c.OtherProperty == "hi")` is not executed unconditionally. How would you model that with LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove this method chaining code from and control everything from the method which calls a(List values)

Well since you're filtering values you could use something like the [LINQKit PredicateBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which would allow you to create a list of filters and apply them to the linq exprssion

However if you're doing more than just filtering you could use create instances of the [`Action<T>` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to represent actions that could be done to a your list and then apply them.

There's also the possibility of using [Continuation Passing Style CPS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/12/22/continuation-passing-style.aspx)  but thinking about how that works makes my ears bleed.

Comment: CPS is nice ... it's just so awkward to use with C# syntax :-/